# How to Geocode address from multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, geocoding, rails-geocoder

I need to [geocode](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) user's address into latitude & longitude to store in database.

Addresses table

```
country_id: int
state_id: int
local_address: string
latitude: float
longitude: float
```

I have separate `countries and states` tables.
So, to get lat & long values I need something like this:

```
geocoded_by :address 
def address
  [local_address, state, country].compact.join(', ')
end
```

But the problem is, this is done in model (Address class) and I need to access other tables: countries & states.

So, can't figure a way out. Any working suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your model you need to have the association to your countries and states tables
I am assuming that you are saving the state id and country_id

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :country

  geocoded_by :address 
  def address
    [local_address, state.name, country.name].compact.join(', ')
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah! It worked!! It needs to make correct associations and use "Model.attribute_name" for joining altogether into single address. Thanks for such a quick response.

Comment: not a problem we have all been there were we need another set of eyes